# Disable default Android TV navigation sound effect Programmatically

Tags: android-tv, background-music, leanback

How to disable sound feedback effect in Android TV Programmatically. If i press navigation button while music service is playing, sound effect mutes music for second. Or may be there is some priorities for music service? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can change it via the AudioManager like this:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, 0 /*or: AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI*/);
```

To get the current notification volume, use

```
audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION)
```

Possible volume values are 0..7.

From API level 23, you can also use AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE.